# Liferay 7.4 OpenID Connect as SP for Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, liferay-7

I'm trying to configure Liferay as an SP with Azure B2C IdP by OpenId Connect.

My issue is that I can't handle what kind of OAuh/oidc flow Liferay start in the portal login process. The first request for login when you configure OpenID Connect Provider in Liferay (and select openid connect on login page) is a redirect for your authorize URL, and Liferay set response_type=code in the URL.It's ok, and Azure B2C cand handled it, asking me for user/pass.

But, then, when IdP response with a code (after succesfull login), like protocol define, Liferay try to parse this like if it were a JWT access token. but isn't it. Because it's a code that Liferay need to validate to request a token for the auth token endpoint (configured in OpenID Connect Provider section on Liferay).

So I received an Internal Error on Liferay login page.

I've followed this procedure,
https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028711312-Authenticating-with-OpenID-Connect

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The B2C configuration is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect).

B2C scopes are usually openid and offline_access.

Did you create a B2C [application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga)?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out that Liferay need the implementation of the user_info endpoint to be able to work with openid.
It's rare because it's not necesary actually. I mean, Liferay go to user_info endpoint after call the authorize one, to get email address of the user, even if this information were in the first authorize token.

Anyways, the solution was implement user_info in B2C, so Liferay is working well now.